# How can I sort a database result base on a custom value inside a special character?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset that returns
`1001(10),  1001(09),  1002(08)`. Is there a way I can sort this dataset into this order where you check the value inside a parenthesis and sort them:

```
1002(08)

1001(09)

1001(10)
```

I only know sorting as way of ORDER BY DESC and ASC, however, this is a weird way of sorting, and is this even possible?

Comment: Short answer: it should be separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to seperate this into two fields, you can do this:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
ORDER BY trim(ltrim(t.my_column, '0123456789'), '()')::int
```

Assuming your strings are always starting with an integer and then have an integer in parantheses.

But you really should think about changing your data model.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [`substring`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/) to parse the values between parenthesis and then cast them to integer in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
ORDER BY substring(col FROM '\(([^\(]*)\)') ASC
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=297e8c26aa1bc07f2d728e296606ba75)

```
WITH j (col) AS (
  VALUES ('1001(10)'),
         ('1001(09)'),
         ('1002(08)')
)
SELECT * FROM j
ORDER BY substring(col FROM '\(([^\(]*)\)') ASC;

   col    
----------
 1002(08)
 1001(09)
 1001(10)
(3 rows)
```